# Random time delay non-integer

Tags: python

I am trying to create a random delay between 0.05634 and 0.15342 I've tried looking at other posts but they all use integer numbers and these numbers aren't hope to see if someone can help :)

Ive tried using the random function and the time.sleep function but nothing seems to work!

Im trying to make a double clicker for a game but when I use the random function it lags everytime I press the mouse button, When I remove the time.sleep function it works without anylag!

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import pyautogui
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Controller
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import time
import random

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.001

random = random.random()
mouse = Controller()


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    time.sleep(random)
    pyautogui.press('home')



with Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: If you tried something, can you show what you tried? Usually a partial solution is far more illustrative of what you're doing than a wordy description.

Comment: from random import randint
from time import sleep

sleep(randint(10,100))

Comment: For new code, edit your question to include that and be sure it's formatted in a way we can easily read it. Comments don't treat it the same way.

Comment: there sorry im new to this

Comment: It's not clear for me what the problem is, if you add a sleep then yes you have a lag, isn't that the point ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with being new. We're just trying to help keep things organized and easy to follow so we can get a solution here.

Comment: polku No it lags my cursor for like 2 seconds

Comment: i believe it is because that these packages use the [win32api.mouse_event](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104592/win32api.mouse_event) function, which clicks the mouse in a specific spot, meaning that while the function is running, the mouse can not move

Answer (score 1):

to answer the question in the title;

```py
import random
import time
time_delay=random.uniform(0.05634,0.15342)
time.sleep(time_delay)
```

however, regarding the lagging time delay, instead of using a standard time delay, have you tried creating your own, maybe replacing the `time.sleep` line with `for i in range(10000000): x=0`, this will create a halt in your program that is different every time, as you can see below;

```py
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(10000000): x=0',number=1)
0.20446060000000443
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(10000000): x=0',number=1)
0.19383630000001517
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(10000000): x=0',number=1)
0.2523204000000021
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(10000000): x=0',number=1)
0.18888549999999782
```

Comment: Hello 3nigma thank you so much for trying to help me! unfortunately this method still lags my cursor, do you have any other idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to detect double clicks? time.sleep halts your entire program...

Comment: Yeah I am trying to get it so if I click once it clicks 2 times for me, I tried using pyautogui.click() but this lags my whole pc out, Ive changed it to pyautogui.press('home') and changed my attack button to HOME this seems to work, But now im trying to make it click in a random delay because if I dont do this the anticheat will pick up the double clicks and I will get banned.

Comment: This still seems to lag my cursor out